# Best Books that shows how to use jQuery with ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, jquery

I have searched the stackoverflow site to find if someone has recommended any good books that show how jQuery can be used with asp.net. All the threads lead to only good jQuery books.

Can anyone recommend me a good book that shows how to use jquery with asp.net? Any upcoming books are also ok

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you should check this book written by a MVP and it has some very good reviews. [51 Tips, Tricks and Recipes using jQuery and ASP.NET Controls](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/order/jQueryASPNETRecipesBook.aspx). Here's what the book says

> In the first book of its kind on using jQuery with ASP.NET Controls, I show you how to use jQuery to solve some common and not-so-common client-side programming challenges while dealing with ASP.NET Controls. This EBook is the result of my practical experience of using jQuery with ASP.NET controls, all in the pursuit of demonstrating techniques to resolve Client-Side programming challenges, quickly

Comment: thanks i think this is the book i want.

Answer (score 2):

I think that ["jQuery for ASP.NET Developers"](http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/WroxTitle/jQuery-for-ASP-NET-Developers.productCd-0470478454.html) book by Wrox is a good one.

Also look at ["51 Tips, Tricks and Recipes using jQuery and ASP.NET Controls"](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/order/jQueryASPNETRecipesBook.aspx) ebook.

Comment: you beat me to it. I just posted the same book :)

Comment: thanks i think this is the book i want